# How to implement constraints for 2 labels between 2 images for xib file

Tags: ios, constraints, xib

**Edit: PLEASE LEAVE A COMMENT IF YOU'RE GOING TO DISLIKE SO I CAN IMPROVE MY QUESTION**

I'm trying to recreate a custom table view cell in my xib file as shown below. The company's square image is on the left. The company's name and company's booth (2 UI Labels) are to the right of the company's image. The star button is to the right of the text and is a square image. I guesstimated that the company's image and favorites button should be about 8px from the top and edge.

[image]

I tried to create 4 constraints for the top, bottom, left, and right of every element (image, 2 UI labels, and button). I also added 1:1 aspect ratio constraint to the image and button to make sure the image would be square. Then I aligned the left edge of the 2 UI labels. I vertically centered the image and the button. However, it came out with no star button and the location and title switched. How do I create this design using constraints?

[image]

Comment: Have you created a bottom constraint for your left `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no difficulty with that.
First if we talk about your left `UIImageView`, Set following constraints,

- Leading constraint
- Fixed Height
- Fixed Width
- Centre Vertically

After that the `UIImageView` on left, set following constraints,

- Trailing space from superview
- Fixed Height
- Fixed Width
- Centre Vertically

Now for both Labels, put them in a `UIView` and give that `UIView` following constraints,

- Leading space from left image view.
- trailing space from right image view.
- top space from superview
- bottom space from superview

Now for upper UILabel, Set following constraints,

- Leading space
- Trailing space
- top space

Now for lower `UILabel`, Set following constraints,

- Leading space
- Trailing space
- top space from upper UILabel
- bottom space

After all this, i think that this will work for you.

Comment: Okay im going to try that! I was wondering if I set a fixed width and height, if the users uses a bigger phone, won't the images look really small?

Comment: The kind of screen you are working right now, The image sizes won't change too much as per device change. So you can go with this solution. I have done this in many apps and never faced any problem. Works fine for me.
If it worked for you, don't forget to up vote.

Comment: As per requirement, give constraints to both `UIImageView ` `top.superview = 8px` instead of `vertically center` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constraints in the image below. It will work for all screen size and for any height of row.[image]